# Defeat multiple insane AI opponents with Zerg

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements, starcraft-zerg

I'd like to be able to beat one or more insane AI opponents with Zerg. Unfortunately I can't because I'm just not skilled enough. :) I'd like to know if anyone else can, however?

I've gotten the achievement to defeat 7 insane AI opponents with Protoss and Terran by turtling and massing carriers or battleships.

Is there any way to turtle or otherwise defeat multiple insane AI opponents with Zerg?

Comment: that's a pretty insane question right there (sorry, I couldn't resist)

Comment: Given the mechanic of zerg (larva) I don't think it's possible. Even if you do nothing but pump drones and build spine/spore crawlers, those are non-army units that you're building. 

Both Terrans and Protoss can build harvesters and units simultaneously while a zerg can't. Eventually you are going to be outnumbered by production.

Given the above, unless you can somehow massively out-macro the computer (which is already nearly impossible on insane because they gather 7 minerals per trip instead of your 5) with extra hatcheries/queens, I don't think you're going to be able to beat 7 insane AI.

Comment: Maybe try an island map? Or a 2v2+ map where you share bases and can take very easy expansions while you mass spine crawler your ramp. Of course you have to find a way to get creep all the way to the ramp quickly...

Answer (score 5):

> Both Terrans and Protoss can build harvesters and units simultaneously while a Zerg can't.
>
> — [Sorean's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24519/defeat-multiple-insane-ai-opponents-with-zerg#comment-35773)

What he says isn't 100% true, you can produce queens for (early) defense while producing Drones.

Which brings you to a [Spanishiwa style](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=207017) way of playing Zerg, where you should root your strategy.

---

The general idea I have on this:

- Do not create Extractors very early until the point you come to upgrading your base.

  **Why?** You don't need gas so early on.
- Focus on getting a queen out and spread creep till the ramp; keep producing queens as defense!

  **Why?** Creep is needed for crawlers and to serve as a speed bonus for your slow queen army...
- Get Spine Crawlers near the ramp and add Spore Crawlers to the mix later on.
- Get a second Hatchery in base, this allows you double the amount of Larva and queens you get.

  **Why?** This kind of exploits the [4OC style](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=173703) of playing, so you produce double as fast. :)
- Get out for an expansion; don't forget your extractors and upgrading your base.

  **Why?** Because you come to a point where you just can't hold it on your base alone...
- Mass up a Brood-Lord army with some defensive Corruptors or whatever unit composition rocks...

---

The effectiveness of this depends on your execution of a Spanishiwa style build order, see for yourself if it's impossible for you at this moment of time. I bet it's possible when one does a lot of practice...

Comment: But you ignored the sentence prior to the one you quoted. Queens are a small exception and certainly not considered part of a core army unit unless you're going towards a transfusing Broodlord/ultralisk type of build. Also a Spanishiwa style does not work vs 7 Insane AI in an FFA. There is no way to hold his natural long enough. Sure he can build a quick macro hatch, but it won't allow him to gather the resources to make effective use of all the extra larva.  *off to test vs 7 Insane AI now that I'm off work.

Comment: (v 7 Zerg Insane) After a little bit of testing, I stand corrected a bit. You do have enough time if they don't cheese you, I tried on megaton. They sent drones at me! WTF?! :P  Fell behind, died, even with a macro hatch. Tried on Abyss, got rushed once, died. I've been doing the Spanishiwa style the entire time as well, 15 hatch, 15 pool, drone up, spines when expo pops. Got farther, but kept getting rolled by mass roach/hydra armies. I kept getting queens as well, and built a macro hatch at home as well. You won't make it to Brood Lord Tech, I got hydras out in time, so infestors might work.

Comment: @Sorean: Interesting, might want to try this over and over myself. :)